# AVL tree rebalancing after deletion

Tags: data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I have the following tree and I have to delete node 5 and then rebalance it. My notes mention that it is rebalanced as the picture #1. Can't it be rebalanced as the picture #2 shows as well or am I missing something? Which criteria should I follow to rebalance it if I have two options? Sorry, I am not so good at paint. Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, both alternatives for rebalancing are correct as they yield search trees (left sucessors are smaller than the root and right successors are are larger than the root for every subtree) and each subtree is balanced, i.e. the heights of leaves differ by at most one.